# Android: Prevent soft keyboard from losing focus when selecting text?

Tags: android, keyboard, focus

I have an `EditText` on my layout and it has the attribute             `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
so that the user can see the bottom text while typing.

But when the user tries to mark some text to copy it while having the keyboard opened, the keyboard *loses focus* (the user can't type anything anymore, but the keyboard is still there) and on some devices (e.g. my Samsung Galaxy Tablet 3) the text scrolls back and most of the text is hidden by an *unselectable* keyboard.

My chat.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chatlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chatView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:divider="#0000" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chatView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/findbattle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/find_a_battle"
            android:src="@drawable/findbattle" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatInput"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.98"
            android:hint="@string/send_message"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add that in the manifest activity and remove it from the layout and see

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue

Comment: you want to keep the focus of your s.keyboard when you copy some text in the screen right

Comment: this is correct

Comment: have a look on my answer!

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe because on my layout has a ´ListView´ that contains the actual ´TextView´? The ´TextView´ is added code-wise and I tried setting the attributes with the set-methods, but it didn't work.

Comment: How can i know you haven't post anything and ask me ! add your  xml

Comment: i've added the xml file

Comment: Where is the XML of your listview  inflator ?

Comment: Try using `adjustResize` instead of `adjustPan`. Given your layout, I don't think `adjustPan` is necessary, and quite frankly I have never found it useful anyway.